# I have tried installing this many times, but always like this, why is this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, mysql-python

Say i'm have problem please help me  "Could not find a version of mysqldb (from versions:) No matching distribution found for mysqldb "
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb is the interface to MySQL database. As mentioned by other posts, MySQLdb doesn't support Python 3.x. I used PyMySQL as the replacement. You need to install it first:

```
pip install PyMySQL or  pip3 install PyMySQL
```

The next step is to replace 'MySQLdb' with 'pymysql' in all the codes, which is intimidating. Luckily, PyMySQL can be loaded as MySQLdb dyanamically.

Comment: import pymysql 
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

This __init__.py would be executed when you run the project